# Change the overflow icon to a new image

Tags: android, overflow-menu

I have an issue with the overflow menu. I need to replace the 3 dots with my image. I tried out several ways but its not working.

In my styles.xml, I have added the following code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverFlowMenu</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverFlowMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOverFlowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow</item>
</style>
```

My application works from Android 4.4 onwards to the latest. Could some one let me know whats wrong behind this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your **AppTheme** style you have taken parent value as **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar**. Are you able to see the action bar at the top of the screen?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes, I have my custom action bar

Comment: then you have no need to apply **android:src** in style file. Just go into your custom action bar layout and apply **android:src** there for particular imageview.

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes, but I need the checkable thing too along with options. So only I went with overflow menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I did programatically. Here goes the code for the same:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.my_overflow);
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this one,which worked properly.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverFlowMenu</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverFlowMenu</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyOverFlowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>
```

For class

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("activity");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: same thing only I said in my question. But it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Your `@drawable/my_overflow` should be a XML drawable like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_overflow_icon_unpressed">
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_overflow_icon_pressed" >
    </item> 
</selector>
```

Of course, make sure you have png drawable files for `my_overflow_icon_unopressed` and `my_overflow_iconPressed`